# Will an object trigger if the source is sacrificed to pay a cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Will *"When/Whenever Foo"* trigger if the source is sacrificed to pay a cost for Foo?

**Examples**

If I activate [Birthing Pod](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Birthing%20Pod)'s ability and sacrifice [Kurkesh, Onakke Ancient](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kurkesh%2C%20Onakke%20Ancient), will Kurkesh trigger, allowing me to copy Birthing Pod's ability?

If I cast [Life Legacy](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Life%20Legacy) and sacrifice [Basilica Screecher](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Basilica%20Screecher) to pay for the cost, will Basilica Screecher trigger, allowing me to extort?

Comment: If anyone knows how to make the Life's Legacy link open in a window like the other cards, please teach me. I couldn't autocard it like the others because the apostrophe breaks the autocard feature.

Comment: Remove the apostrophe, and the card search will find it anyway.

Comment: @BrianS Actually you have to remove the apostrophe and the following s. The card name will look incorrect in the text of the post, but it will link correctly, and it will still be clear what card is being talked about.

Comment: In both of your examples, the trigger condition is putting something on the stack. Is that intended?

Comment: @murgtroid99 It was not intentional. If you can think of a case where paying a cost does not result in adding something to the stack (such as activating a mana ability) feel free to use that in your answer.

Comment: I don't think there are any existing cards where paying a cost by sacrificing a permanent could cause that permanent's ability to trigger, but there might be theoretically valid abilities that could lead to that happening.

Comment: On the other hand, I suspect that if any such ability *was* printed, it would make the interpretation of 603.6d ambiguous. So, they'd either change the rule or not print it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a creature with a triggered ability leaves the battlefield before the triggered ability's condition occurs, the ability is not triggered. Rule 603.6d says

> **Normally, objects that exist immediately after an event are checked to see if the event matched any trigger conditions.** Continuous effects that exist at that time are used to determine what the trigger conditions are and what the objects involved in the event look like. However, some triggered abilities must be treated specially. Leaves-the-battlefield abilities, abilities that trigger when a permanent phases out, abilities that trigger when an object that all players can see is put into a hand or library, abilities that trigger specifically when an object becomes unattached, abilities that trigger when a player loses control of an object, and abilities that trigger when a player planeswalks away from a plane will trigger based on their existence, and the appearance of objects, prior to the event rather than afterward. The game has to "look back in time" to determine if these abilities trigger.

In your specific situation, [rule 601.2h](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Casting_Spells) says

> **Once the steps described in 601.2a–g are completed, the spell becomes cast.** Any abilities that trigger when a spell is cast or put onto the stack trigger at this time. If the spell's controller had priority before casting it, he or she gets priority.

One of those steps is paying costs. Activated abilities follow the same steps. So in both of your examples, the creature is no longer on the battlefield by the time the spell is cast or the ability is activated.