# Can I Activate Codie when Casting Burnt Offering on Codie?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have 3 source (land/artifact) and codie on board. I'm attempting to activate [Codie, Vociferous Codex](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Codie%2C%20Vociferous%20Codex)'s ability with tapping three mana source on board and casting [Burnt Offering](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burnt%20Offering) at instant speed. Does codie successfully add 5 mana to mana pool along with the instant-cascade-like effect?

- I do recall someone showing me that this sort of action is legal but I don't recall the specific incident that represents something like this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here - are you attempting to sacrifice Codie as part of the cost of casting Burnt Offering? If so, that's answered in many questions here already, for example here https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/20694/will-an-object-trigger-if-the-source-is-sacrificed-to-pay-a-cost

Comment: That question doesn't seem relevant here

Comment: Thanks, the SE question you sent was revolved around passive ability triggers which is different in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, there is no way to both sacrifice Codie to cast Burnt Offering and spend the mana generated by Burnt Offering to pay to activate Codie's ability.**

Burnt Offering does not produce any mana until the spell resolves. If you sacrifice Codie to cast Burnt Offering, there is too broad a gap between losing Codie and gaining the mana, so there is no opportunity to activate Codie's ability using that mana.

---

It is possible to sacrifice Codie to activate a mana ability and spend that mana to pay for its ability. For example, if you control [Ashnod's Altar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashnod%27s%20Altar), you can start activating Codie's ability, and while you are doing that, you can activate Ashnod's Altar's ability sacrificing Codie, and then you can finish activating Codie's ability using that mana to pay the cost.

---

It is also possible to activate Codie's ability while casting a spell and sacrifice Codie to pay that spell's additional cost if you already have the mana to activate Codie's ability. Practically speaking, this almost always has the same effect as activating Codie's ability before starting to cast that spell.

Comment: Codie's activated ability is a mana ability. To quote, "Codie's activated ability is a mana ability. It can't be countered or responded to, and you can activate it while casting a spell. If you do, that spell is "the next spell" you cast this turn." [mtg:Codie, Vociferous Codex]

Comment: You're right. I missed that.

Comment: I corrected that mistake. The conclusion is still the same

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've been caught up with "601.2g If the total cost includes a mana payment, the player then has a chance to activate mana abilities (see rule 605, “Mana Abilities”). Mana abilities must be activated before costs are paid", but burnt offering is not a mana ability so it can't add mana to mana pool prior to passing priority and resolving the spell. "spells aren’t mana abilities."(605.5)